# Subclass of SKEmitterNode not calling init or deist

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am able to initialize this class, and see my particle effect, but the subclass doesn't call init() or deinit. Why?

```
class Particles: SKEmitterNode {

    var test: Int?

    override init() {
        test = 1
        super.init()
        println("created particle emitter")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {

        println("destroyed particle emitter")
    }
}
```

This is called from GameScene()

let particle = Particles(fileNamed:"test")

and I tried this to:

var particle: Particles?

viewDidLoad:

particle = Particles(fileNamed:"test")

Comment: How are you creating your `Particles` instance?

Comment: I tried may ways: var particle = Particles(fileNamed: "test"), let particle = Particles(fileNamed: "test"), var particle: Particles? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry about that, while I was starting my sentence I hit enter. Thanks again, I really appreciate this.

Comment: I am personally starting to feel like Swift isn't ready for primetime. It seems to fight you all the way.

Comment: Yeah, it does. To what I found out `fileNamed` should be a convenient initializer and therefor should call `init`... I already started writing parts of my apps back in C/Objective-C because of things like this...

Answer (score 3):

Subclasses can only call superclass designated initialiser so cannot call `super.init(fileNamed:)`. A workaround is not to make an initialiser at all but make a class method and perform setup code in there. 
I copied the code apple provides to unarchive an sks scene and changed it to work with your emitter. The method finds the particle file if it exists and unarchives it as a Particles object:

```
class Particles: SKEmitterNode {
    var test: Int?

    class func fromFile(file : String) -> Particles? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKEmitterNode")
            let p = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as Particles
            archiver.finishDecoding()

            //Perform any setup here
            p.test=11

            return p
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
let p=Particles.fromFile("MyParticle")!
p.test=0
p.particleSpeed=10
addChild(p)
```

Comment: First, p.test = 0 or p.test! = 0 causes a crash. Two, I really want to understand this language. init(fileNamed: name) is a convince initializer, so it must call it's init, right? So why doesn't it call Particles.init( )?

Comment: Also, I don't know if deinit is being called or I just have a leak somewhere.

Comment: This returns a Particles object whereas my other code was returning an SKEmitterNode object. Sorry, I didn't even test my other code.

Comment: But why can't we use fileNamed?